# i want to position my :after content in mobile view or in less resolutions

Tags: html, css, testimonials

I have HTML and CSS for testimonial, which is in [JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9zrm6bgj/).The problem here is ":after" content is misplacing in mobile view or it is not properly alligned, i need to align it, so that it is need to be in constant position in mobile view as well as normal view, anyone have some ideas?

```
 <div>
 <div class="testi-inno" id="testi-one">

<p>“this place having some text, which is of lorger or amaller size”</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="testi-img" style="clear:both;">
<img src="" alt=" " width="70" height="70"/>
 </div>
<p class="testi-par">name of client</p>
<p class="testi-paras">designation</p>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.testi-inno p:after {
   content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #fff;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 19%;
  left: 42%;

}
.testi-inno{
background:#fff;
margin:10px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; 
}
.testi-inno p{
margin:15px;
margin-bottom:15px !important;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;

}
.testi-img img{
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-left: 34%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9zrm6bgj/)

Comment: You mean the **caret** or the down arrow?

Comment: down arrow! using ".testi-inno p:after" .

Comment: Where exactly you want to position that?

Comment: It is in correction as of now.! But it moves bottom when the screen size is less, what we can do to rectify that?
or what can we do to fix it same with testimonial, when the screen size reduces?

Comment: Is it really positioned below the p or the box-shadow?

Comment: `.testi-inno p:after {
   content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #fff;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 19%;
  left: 42%;

}`
after p !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Solution , Just Use Position Relative in " .testi-inno " Because Position:relative Control Position:absolute

```
 .testi-inno{
    background:#fff;
    margin:10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
  }
```

In Your Case Your After Value=  top: 19%; or left: 42%; Work According to Window Walls , but After you use Position:relative, then top :19% or left :42% work accroding to your .testi-inno Div , So It's work Properly on Mobile Device. and Secound mistake is If you need to center the arrow use left : 50%; not 42 % .

```
 .testi-inno p:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #fff;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    margin:0 0 0 -20px;
 }
```

Just check my [JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9zrm6bgj/5/) -

Comment: It worked like a charm, Perfect!, sorry i don't know it earlier, but i gained some knowledge from this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just **change** the `.testi-inno p:after` to `.testi-inno:after` and `top: 19%;` to `margin-top: -15px;`.

**Here's the [JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/9zrm6bgj/6/).**

**E.g.**

**Modify**

```
.testi-inno p:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #fff;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 19%;
  left: 42%;
}
```

**To**

```
.testi-inno:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #fff;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  margin-top: -15px;
  left: 48%;
}
```

Hope it helps.